# magento getpath() extract value

Tags: php, magento, extract

I would like to request information of how to extract a particular value in getpath() function.

currently I placed the following information:

```
<?php $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>
<?php echo $currentCat->getPath()?>
```

and the system echo 1/2/5 , where 1 is root of root, 2 is catalog root and 5 is the first simple category.

I would like to extract the third value only (number 5 in this example) in that serie of categories to echo that info only in the page but i tried different appraches with no success.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php),  [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

```
<?php echo end(explode("/", $currentCat->getPath())); ?>
```

---

> do you know if I can place a value to retrieve always that 3 level no matter if im placed in another subcategory

Should looks like this:

```
<?php 
   $exp = explode("/", $currentCat->getPath());
   echo $exp[2];
?>
```

I would recommend you to take a look at [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) again :)

Comment: great, it works to get the current category value! do you know if I can place a value to retrieve always that 3 level no matter if im placed in another subcategory? eg: 1/2/5/22/34 and retrieve only 5?. brgds